# Eager loading associated models in ActiveAdmin sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

I've got an ActiveAdmin index page

```
ActiveAdmin.register Bill
```

And I am trying to display links to associated models

```
index do
  column "User" do |bill|
   link_to bill.user.name, admin_user_path(bill.user)
  end
end
```

But I run into the N+1 query problem - there's a query to fetch each user.

Is there a way of eager loading the bills' users?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is an answer on a different post, but it describes well what you need to do here.

```
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      Bill.includes(:user)
    end
  end
```

Here, you will need to make sure you follow scope.  So if your controller is scope_to'ed, then you will want to replace the model name above with the scope_to'ed param.

Comment: it is not paginated = result can be huge

Answer (score 36):

The way to do this is to override the `scoped_collection` method (as noted in Jeff Ancel's answer) but call `super` to retain the existing scope. This way you retain any pagination/filtering which has been applied by ActiveAdmin, rather than starting from scratch.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Bill do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      super.includes :user
    end
  end

  index do
    column "User" do |bill|
     link_to bill.user.name, admin_user_path(bill.user)
    end
  end
end
```

As noted in official documentation at http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html

Answer (score 11):

The existing answers were right at the time, but ActiveAdmin supports eager loading with a much more convenient syntax now:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Bill do
  includes :user
end
```

See the docs for [resource customization](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html)

Comment: Yes, [this eager loading DSL](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#eager-loading) was [added by Timo in 2014](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/3464).

Answer (score 2):

I've found `scoped_collection` loads all the entries, instead of just the ones for the page you are displaying. I think a better option is `apply_collection_decorator` that will only preload the items you are effectively displaying.

```
controller do
  def apply_collection_decorator(collection)
    collection.includes(:user)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as of Activeadmin 2.13

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT EDIT NOTE :** what follows is actually **false**, see the comments for an explanation. However I leave this answer where it stands because it seems I'm not the only one to get confused by the guides, so maybe someone else will find it useful.

i assume that

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

so [according to RoR guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference) it is already eager-loaded :

> There’s no need to use :include for immediate associations – that is,
>   if you have Order belongs_to :customer, then the customer is
>   eager-loaded automatically when it’s needed.

you should check your SQL log if it's true (didn't know that myself, i was just verifying something about `:include` to answer you when i saw this... let me know)

Comment: i think it's very doubtful, but who knows ?

Comment: _the customer is eager-loaded automatically when it’s needed_ - that just means, if you have 1000 orders and iterate over them, you call `order1.customer`, and `customer1` is loaded because it is needed. Then you access `order2.customer`, but hey, you didn't say you were going to need it, so another query to database is done. But it still doesn't know you're going to need `customer3` on your next iteration, so you'll get 1000 queries instead of 1.

Comment: thanks for clearing that. I find this way to expose things confusing, but english is not my native language.

Comment: That is talking about adding :include to the definition of an association, and saying an association doesn't need to self-include.  I believe that's rather different than adding an includes call to a scope which should eager load the added models.  (I say 'should' because...well guess why I'm on this site right now)